# On which HTML element should I place ng-if?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to place asterisks (*) next to required fields based on a boolean value.

If I do it with a `<p>` tag Visual Studio complains that it's invalid to place a `<p>` tag inside a `<label>`.

```
<label>Title: <p ng-if="titleRequired">*</p></label>
```

Similarly if I try using a `<div>` instead, I get a similar complaint that divs can't be placed inside of a label.

```
<label>Title: <div ng-if="titleRequired">*</div></label>
```

If I place the `ng-if` on the `<label>` I run into the problem of wanting the asterisk in red but the label text in standard black.

```
<label ng-if="titleRequired">Title: *</label>
```

I can try getting around that with a font tag but it's obsolete.

```
<label ng-if="titleRequired">Title: <font color="red">*</font></label>
```

All of these will render in Chrome, but I'd like to use valid markup if possible. Is there a way to do this with valid markup?

Comment: Just use a `<span>`. VS complains because it is not "valid" to put block-level elements inside inline-level elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `<span>` instead of `<div>`

```
<label>Title: <span ng-if="titleRequired">*</span></label>
```

then you can customize your  element with some CSS.

```
<style>
    span { color: #FF0000; }
</style>
```